# linq query cause System.AccessViolationException

Tags: vb.net, exception, linq-to-sql

I have a strange exception executing a simple linq query, the query is expressed in VB.NET (sorry..). The exception is, as the title says: "System.AccessViolationException", the full exception message chain is

> "System.Web.HttpUnhandledException: Exception of type
> 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. --->
> System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected
> memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt. "

The strange behavior is:

1. The exception is thrown randomly
2. The exception is thrown just on production server and not on the same test server
3. The query executed against the production db using LinqPad works perfectly

This is the full exception stack trace:
[image: Exception full stack trace]

In the stack trace the erased methods calls makes a query using the Single() linq method.

We think the issue is related to a KB installed on the production server with windows update, but it's clear, we dont't know it exactly

Any idea what could be the real issue?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You think it might be because of a KB installed on the production server. Did you manage to find that one? And also, did you compare both environments? It might be due to a different configuration and/or installed things. Your LINQ query, how does it look like?

Comment: We found what KB and we installed the same on the testing server.. and yet the testing server works and the production not. The thing to note is that we experienced the issue and the exception after the installation of all set of KBs. Just for clear, the day before KBs installations everything works, the day it self not! And yes both machines are identical...

Comment: The servers for test and prod may be identical in software installed but are the permissions and project code the same? Anyway can you rollback the KB installed to rule it out? Does this error occur only when new code is deployed? If so you may need to ensure that the aspnet or account running this code has permissions to read/write.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, you tested memory or not?

Comment: just for clarification: this was the story: we deployed the application in production 1 month ago, and for 20 days everything works well without any troubles, 10 days ago, the "server support crew" installed the latest security KB, after that, the morning after, we begun to experience that exception. Keep in mind, before everything works, after none.. So our battle is to convince the "server support crew" that a KB brokes the system....

Comment: Just out of curiosity... why do you say "sorry" for working with VB.net?

Comment: @RolandDeschain because us VB.NET developers like to humorously apologize for not using a "real" language.  I sometimes do it, myself.  (It's like a Canadian apologizing for being Canadian.)

Answer (score 0):

All the symptoms points to a bad memory stick on the server, or other hardware issues (overheating/overclocking). It could also be caused by a virus. Access violations happen when a pointer in memory gets corrupted and ends up referencing a protected memory area. I would recommend you transfer the image to another physical machine altogether and run a full MEMTEST86 run on the server, and give the housing a thorough cleaning, replace old fans, etc... If the problem is not isolated this way then reinstall the production server from scratch on a fresh drive.