# LINQ to SQL: intermittent AccessViolationException wrapped in TargetInvocationException

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql, crash

Since a few weeks we are experiencing W3WP-crashes with our ASP.Net web application. These started after our webservers were updated. Our application did not change and has been stable for years.
Our situation seems to be a lot like [this earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17749075/linq-query-cause-system-accessviolationexception). And [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26176400/linq-to-entities-predicating-on-a-datetime-field-causes-accessviolationexceptio) might also be related, though in our case the queries run fine in 99.9% of the times used.

We use a lot of uncompiled LINQ queries and tried if compiling them would prevent these crashes. The number of crashes decreased drastically, but they still do occur.

Also wrapping our queries in a `try catch` and then catching the `TargetInvocationException` does not work. The exception is not caught.

When a crash happens, we get a WER-report and can retreive a crash dump.
A stack trace from a dump for an uncompiled query typically looks like this:

> at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
>   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
>   at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
>   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInvocation(InvocationExpression invoke)
>   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(Expression node)
>   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitExpression(Expression exp)
>   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitBinary(BinaryExpression b)
>   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(Expression node)
>   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitExpression(Expression exp)
>   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitBinary(BinaryExpression b)
>   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(Expression node)
>   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.Visit(Expression node)
>   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitWhere(Expression sequence, LambdaExpression predicate)
>   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitSequenceOperatorCall(MethodCallExpression mc)
>   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(Expression node)
>   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitWhere(Expression sequence, LambdaExpression predicate)
>   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitSequenceOperatorCall(MethodCallExpression mc)
>   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(Expression node)
>   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitSelect(Expression sequence, LambdaExpression selector)
>   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitSequenceOperatorCall(MethodCallExpression mc)
>   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(Expression node)
>   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitDistinct(Expression sequence)
>   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitSequenceOperatorCall(MethodCallExpression mc)
>   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(Expression node)
>   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.ConvertOuter(Expression node)
>   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.BuildQuery(Expression query, SqlNodeAnnotations annotations)
>   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query)
>   at System.Data.Linq.DataQuery'1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
>   at System.Linq.Buffer'1..ctor(IEnumerable'1 source)
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable'1 source)

The stack trace from a dump for a compiled query looks like:

> at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(System.Object, System.Object[], System.Signature, Boolean)
>   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(System.Object, System.Object[], System.Object[])
>   at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(System.Object[])
>   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.AssignParameters(System.Data.Common.DbCommand, System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1, System.Object[], System.Object)
>   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.Execute(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression, QueryInfo, System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.IObjectReaderFactory, System.Object[], System.Object[], System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.ICompiledSubQuery[], System.Object)
>   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.ExecuteAll(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression, QueryInfo[], System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.IObjectReaderFactory, System.Object[], System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.ICompiledSubQuery[])
>   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider+CompiledQuery.Execute(System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider, System.Object[])
>   at System.Data.Linq.CompiledQuery.ExecuteQuery(System.Data.Linq.DataContext, System.Object[])

Does anyone know what might have changed the behavior our application? We know it was "an update" (but not exactly which one), but we are more interested in it's technical background.
Of course, we would also welcome a solution to prevent our application from crashing.

Comment: Jacco: did you have any luck nailing this down?  We're having the same issue, but with a Windows service.

Comment: No, we did not find the exact KB. We're decreasing the number of crashes and hope for MS fix this in another KB.

Comment: We are having the same issue with a windows service.  We just converted it from x32 to x64, I'm not sure if that is related at all.

Comment: Is your application targeting .NET 4.5.1?

Comment: @jhilden , our application is also x64.

Comment: And @DanLing , we are targeting .NET 4.5.

Comment: we have similiar problem in our windows service with nhibernate. If you found solution, pls write here.

Comment: Seems like the problem is re-surfacing, since you are the second person this week asking for this. I'm sorry, we did not find a solution.
We decreased the number of crashes by compiling our most used LINQ-queries. For some this might help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I thought I would post a solution, that we found to this issue, because we started experiencing the problem recently.

We have many servers that run our code just fine but only 1 was crashing a couple of times a week with this error. I believe this server was on .net 4.5.2.

We opened a ticket with Microsoft since the unhandled exception was happening in their stack.

They looked at our dump and came back with this solution which worked.

> A new fix is available at 
>   https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3139544
>
> It would be better if you move to .net 4.6.1

I hope this solution will help anyone else that finds themselves reading this.

Comment: +1 as this is looking exactly like the issue I've been experiencing. 1-3 crashes a day, just as described - this only started happening once .NET 4.5.2 was installed and during periods of heavier load. Nodes with 4.5.2 crash intermittently, nodes without it are fine. After a call with MS, similar outcome - known issue, recommendation was to update to 4.6.x.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without seeing any of your Linq Code but I would venture a wild guess that an it's an internal (casting) error with the linq library you are using.

As you mentioned that you upgraded recently
(which .NET version did you upgrade from and to ?)

I had similar issue which was resolved by installing windows updates, which you say you have done with some resulting success?

Try to identify the user inputs that cause error. Try to handle the casting yourself rather than relying on Linq